# copy to android clipboard in nvim from termux

Tags: termux, copy-paste, copying

I use neovim on termux on android 11
i commonly use `:y` to yank/copy text to nvim clipboard

then paste it to another files

recently I've tried using [helix-editor](https://helix-editor.com)(hx) looks and feels so similar to neovim(with nvchad/spacevim) with a bunch of themes

in its normal mode there is a command `:clipboard-yank`
which literally **Yank main selection into system clipboard.** after selection of required text.

and similar function is also available on tmux too..

but in nvim it doesn't copy to system clipboard

i tried searching for this function and fond some solutions but those didnt worked for me

```
set clipboard=unnamed
set clipboard=unnamedplus
set clipboard+=unnamed
```

or these `"*y` `"+y`

so, is thre any way to copy to system clipboard